# Create a security identifier for the current domain

Tags: c#, windows, security

I want to create a security identifier for `AccountDomainUsersSid`. The problem is that I can't figure out how to get the sid for the current domain (i.e. the domain that the current user is logged in to).

```
var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AccountDomainUsersSid, /* what do I write here? */);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[SecurityIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0wwwkby.aspx) has an [AccountDomainSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.securityidentifier.accountdomainsid.aspx) property.

The [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.user.aspx) property of the [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e599ywa6.aspx) is a SecurityIdentifier.

WindowsIdentity has the [GetCurrent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfs49sw0.aspx) method that reutrns the current WindowsIdentity.

So this will write out the AccountDomainSid of the Current user

```
   WindowsIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
   Console.WriteLine(id.User.AccountDomainSid);
```